# Will Android MODEL and MANUFACTURER be unique to a given device?

Tags: android, model, device

For fun, I'm creating a database containing Android devices and their screen widths and heights.  I'm currently using the following as the key:

android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER + "-" + android.os.Build.MODEL

Example keys and the (actual devices) are:

- Amazon-Kindle Fire (Kindle Fire)
- samsung-SGH-T679 (Samsung Exhibit 2)
- asus-Nexus 7 (Google Nexus 7)
- samsung-SCH-I800 (Samsung GalaxyTab)

Is that a valid key?  Or could multiple physical devices have the same MANUFACTURER and MODEL values?  For instance, if Amazon releases Kindle Fire 2, could the MODEL value be the same as the original version?

It seems to me that it could be possible for a manufacturer to release a new version of a device without changing the model, but it seems unlikely.  So maybe it's good enough for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: Looks okay to me. I couldn't imagine why a device would share duplicate model numbers (unique to manufacturer)

Comment: It really depends on the OEM. So you can never be sure. But most cases this should be fine. But the bigger problem could be rooted phones can change these values just by changing Build.prop. So occasionally you might get wrong value. Especially since many Custom roms try to copy build.prop values from Nexus Series devices

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'm gonna go for it since I don't have great alternatives.